# Should the word "worthwhile" be followed by a to-infinitive or gerund?

Tags: grammar

> It's worthwhile to say

or

> It's worthwhile saying?

Answer (score 1):

Both occur, but the infinitive is more common (slightly to my surprise: the gerund feels more natural to me).

A search in GloWBe (The international corpus of web-based English) shows 1694 instances of "worthwhile to [verb]" but only 592 of "worthwhile [verb]ing".

Further, I should point out that the instances of "It's worthwhile to [verb]" and "It's worthwhile [verb]ing" are only 182 and 88 respectively, as against 8335 for "It's worth [verb]ing". I.e., "worthwhile" is not very common in this construction at all: most of the examples are the slightly different construction "You might find it worthwhile ..."

Comment: I suppose on reflection my comment about *needing* the infinitive after *worthwhile* wasn't really defensible. All I can say is that relatively speaking it's so unusual to use either verb form after *worthwhile* that my internal "grammar / idiomacy checker" jumped to conclusions. We usually use it in contexts like *That's worthwhile*, with no verb form at all - if the activity itself has to be identified we're *much* more likely to use ***worth***, as your figures show.

Answer (score 1):

Either might work, but depending on the context, one or the other might be strikingly better.

> It was not worthwhile trying to impress a man of that sort.

(Joseph Conrad, *Typhoon*)

In that context, "worthwhile to try to" seems clumsy to me, although perhaps not strikingly so.

> The others could not see how deep he had gone, so it might be worthwhile to try and rescue him.

(Mark Twain, *A Tramp Abroad*)

In that construction, "trying" would not work without changing the following phrasing:

- "...so it might be worthwhile trying to rescue him."
- "...so it might be worthwhile trying and rescuing him."

In context, given the character of the speaker and the narrative situation, I prefer the original phrasing (Twain's phrasing).