# 'Worth' vs 'worthwhile' + infinitive

Tags: meaning, grammar

I stumbled upon a sentence:

> It is likely to perform poorly because the smallest subtasks are too small to be worthwhile splitting up.

Basically my question is, is the usage of 'worthwhile' correct here? I would expect it to be 'worth' instead (at least that's what I see much more often with such meaning).

I looked up [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301231/should-the-word-worthwhile-be-followed-by-a-to-infinitive-or-gerund) question, but it seems to be using 'worthwhile' in a slightly different sense (succeeding verb implies an 'initial' action, not a related 'equal-worth' one).

Comment: ***Worth or worthwhile?*** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/worth-or- - http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv271.shtml

Comment: *Too small to be worth splitting up* OR *too small for splitting up to be worthwhile*.  I don't know how to explain it, but those are the two basic choices.  They're functionally equivalent so you can just choose the one that has the right sound for your ear.